# How to compare two arrays key value pairs using php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. i want to compare two array collection.

A Array Collection

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => 334
        )
) 
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
           [id] => 338
        )
)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
           [id] => 343
        )
)
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
           [item_id] => 376
        )
)
```

B Array Collection:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
           [id] => 343
        )
) 
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
           [id] => 334
        )
)
```

Output:

```
Exists
Not
Exists
Not
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_diff () and array_intersect() for that

Answer (score 0):

Iterate between the first array members and use the [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check each member with second array.

```
$FirstArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$SecondArray = array(1, 3);

for($i = 0; $i < count($FirstArray); $i++){
    if(in_array($FirstArray[i], $SecondArray)){
        echo "Exists" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    else {
        echo "Doesn't Exists!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

it should output

```
Exists
Doesn't Exists!
Exists
Doesn't Exists!
Doesn't Exists!
```

Comment: @radhajesus Here is an example. BUT AND A BIG BUT: You should have gone to that link and my answer without an example was enough for you to get it done. you see the down votes to your question? it means: "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: i have retrieve only else part result.

Comment: oh i just noticed that you have arrays in arrays. why is that?

Comment: @radhajesus updated the answer with complete code. You should be able to get it working with your nested array.

Comment: Please use my array collection and then compare

Comment: @radhajesus We don't have such array collection in php. put them into a php file you will be hit with an error. stop asking people to do your job and  learn how to ask questions. [READ THIS](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) about "How To Ask Questions The Smart Way". Always Always thank people for the favor they are doing for you. All of the smart guys here are devoting their valuable time to answer questions for FREE. You should learn to say thank you.